# Read xml file without .xml extension into R

Tags: xml, r

I have a problem reading xml file into R. The problem is, that this xml file does not have a .xml extension.

I would usually follow the approach described below:

```
library(XML)

xml.url <- "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/plant_catalog.xml"
```

Use the xmlTreeParse and readLines function to parse xml file:

```
xmlfile <- xmlTreeParse(readLines(xml.url))
```

However, I have no idea how to parse the content from the web page below. It has no .xml extension.

```
my_file <- 
  paste0("http://ec.europa.eu/public_opinion/cf/",
         "exp_feed.cfm?keyID=1&nationID=",
         "11,1,27,28,17,2,16,18,13,32,6,3,4,",
         "22,33,7,8,20,21,9,23,31,34,24,12,19,",
         "35,29,26,25,5,14,10,30,15,",
         "&startdate=1973.09&enddate=",
         "2014.06")

my_xml_file <- xmlTreeParse(readLines(my_file))
```

I get this error:

```
Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE7 0x6F 0x6E 0x20
Error: 1: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xE7 0x6F 0x6E 0x20
```

So, the web page does not have an extension, and the parsing throws an error that is related to encoding. I tried my luck with encoding argument in functions above...no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't related to the lack of `xml` extension. That doesn't really matter.

The problem seems to be with the encoding of the file. Things seem to get funny in this region:

```
xx <- readLines(my_file); 
xx[114633:114646]
```

The XML parser does not believe that is proper UTF-8 encoding

You can convert the data in R with

```
yy <- iconv(ll, to="UTF-8")
my_xml_file <- xmlTreeParse(yy)
```

**Note**: This will take out the lines with bad bytes. This means you will be missing data. The rows that are lost are

```
which(is.na(yy))
# [1] 114637 114643 114685 114755 114776 114832 
# [7] 114881 114895 114902 115422 115429 115436
```

so its the same as

```
my_xml_file <- xmlTreeParse(xx[-which(is.na(yy))])
```

Luckily your file still parses without the missing lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting it into R first using **httr** and then letting the `content` function spit it out into a more usable format:

```
library('httr')
my_file <- 
  paste0("http://ec.europa.eu/public_opinion/cf/",
         "exp_feed.cfm?keyID=1&nationID=",
         "11,1,27,28,17,2,16,18,13,32,6,3,4,",
         "22,33,7,8,20,21,9,23,31,34,24,12,19,",
         "35,29,26,25,5,14,10,30,15,",
         "&startdate=1973.09&enddate=",
         "2014.06")
x <- GET(my_file)
z <- xmlToList(content(x))
```

Result:

```
> str(z, 3)
List of 1
 $ Table:List of 2
  ..$ Grid       :List of 35
  .. ..$ AxisZ:List of 2
  .. ..$ AxisZ:List of 2
  .. ..$ AxisZ:List of 2
  .. ..$ AxisZ:List of 2
  .. ..$ AxisZ:List of 2
  .. ..$ AxisZ:List of 2
  .. ..$ AxisZ:List of 2
  .. ..$ AxisZ:List of 2
  .. ..$ AxisZ:List of 2
  .. ..$ AxisZ:List of 2
```